# Livestream playback on Hololens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, uwp, hololens, sharpdx

I have encountered the following problem
My task is as follows, I need to play streaming video (raw h264 video over UDP protocol) on a 3d object. At the moment I'm using FFmpegInteropX to set a MediaSource to a Windows object.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer.
Media Player works in frame server mode, then I subscribe to the videoFrameAvailable event and transmit the resulting frame to Unity

The problem is that the performance on Hololens2 (UWP) is quite low, I can't get enough smoothness and low latency if I use texture sizes greater than 720x720. At the same time, if I run the application on a PC, I can play everything up to 4096x4096 smoothly and without delay.
Perhaps someone has some ideas on how to improve performance on Hololens2?

```
private SoftwareBitmap frameServerDest = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, 1024,1024,BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied );
private UnityEngine.Texture2D tex = new UnityEngine.Texture2D(frameServerDest.PixelWidth, frameServerDest.PixelHeight, UnityEngine.TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

private async void InitializeMediaPlayer(){
FFmpegInteropLogging.SetDefaultLogProvider();
                FFmpegInteropConfig configuration = new FFmpegInteropConfig()
                {
                    MaxVideoThreads = 8,
                    SkipErrors = uint.MaxValue,
                    DefaultBufferTime = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    FastSeek = true,
                    VideoDecoderMode = VideoDecoderMode.ForceFFmpegSoftwareDecoder,
                };
                configuration.FFmpegOptions.Add("tune", "zerolatency");
                configuration.FFmpegOptions.Add("flags", "low_delay");
                configuration.FFmpegOptions.Add("fflags", "discardcorrupt+shortest+sortdts+ignidx+nobuffer");
                decoder = await FFmpegInteropMSS.CreateFromUriAsync("udp://127.0.0.1:9005",configuration)

                var mediaStreamSource = decoder.GetMediaStreamSource();
                mediaStreamSource.BufferTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                Debug.WriteLine($"{decoder.CurrentVideoStream.CodecName} {decoder.CurrentVideoStream.DecoderEngine} {decoder.CurrentVideoStream.HardwareDecoderStatus}  {decoder.CurrentVideoStream.PixelWidth} x {decoder.CurrentVideoStream.PixelHeight}");
              var FrameServer = new Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer() { IsVideoFrameServerEnabled = true };
                FrameServer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamSource);
                FrameServer.RealTimePlayback = true;
                FrameServer.VideoFrameAvailable += MediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable;
                FrameServer.Play();
}

//FrameAvailable:
  private void MediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer sender, object args)
        {
           CanvasDevice canvasDevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
            using (CanvasBitmap canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(canvasDevice, frameServerDest))
            {
               
                sender.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(canvasBitmap);
                byte[] bytes = canvasBitmap.GetPixelBytes();

                if (AppCallbacks.Instance.IsInitialized())
                {
                    AppCallbacks.Instance.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
                    {

                        tex.LoadRawTextureData(bytes);
                        tex.Apply();
                        Display.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.RawImage>().texture = tex;
                    }, false);
                }
                GC.Collect();
            }
         }
```

My FFmpeg output setting
`ffmpeg -r 60   -f gdigrab   -i desktop  -f h264 -framerate 60  -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -threads 8 -thread_type slice  udp://127.0.0.1:9005`

UPDATE:
Hello, I did some work.
What I've done:

1. I have established a direct connection via usb-s - etnernet
2. I begin to look towards using directx surface

I found the following way to get d3d11 device using by Unity
For this I had to use the library SharpDX, and similar  thread  https://forum.unity.com/threads/d3d11-texture2d-blitting-framerate.562552

But there are problems that I can't solve yet:
1 FFmpeg works only in the VideoDecoderMode = VideoDecoderMode.Automatic or VideoDecoderMode.ForceFFmpegSoftwareDecoder mode;
2 In the event handler (videoframe_available), there is still a very large load on the Garbage Collector, and apparently this causes performance problems. Moreover, the performance suffers only on Hololens.
In other  VideoDecoderMode`s, the stream parameters are determined, but the videoframe_available event never fires. Latency is approx to zero, but perfomance still not very good

Perhaps there are ideas how to solve the problem with GarbageColletor?

```
private SoftwareBitmap frameServerDist = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, 780, 780, 
     BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        private FFmpegInteropMSS decoder;

        private UnityEngine.GameObject Display;
        private UnityEngine.Texture2D targetTexture;
        private UnityEngine.GameObject MainCamera;
        private SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device dstDevice;
        private SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext dstContenxt;
        private SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D m_DstTexture;
        private SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device srcDevice;
        private SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext srcContext;
        private static DataRectangle _rect;

        private SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription Texture2DDescription = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription()
        {

            ArraySize = 1,
            BindFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            Usage = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Immutable, //GPU Only
            CpuAccessFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
            Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
            MipLevels = 1,
            OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription()
            {
                Count = 1,
                Quality = 0
            }
        };
```

```
//This event occurs when UnityEngine Initialized 
  private void AppCallbacks_Initialized()
        {

            srcDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware);
            srcContext = srcDevice.ImmediateContext;

            UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
            {
                Display = UnityEngine.GameObject.Find("Display");
                targetTexture = null;
                //Create texture for get Device and Device context 
                UnityEngine.Texture2D deviceTexture = new UnityEngine.Texture2D(frameServerDist.PixelWidth, frameServerDist.PixelHeight, UnityEngine.TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
                IntPtr txPtr = deviceTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr();
                SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D dstTextureX = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(txPtr);
                dstDevice = dstTextureX.Device;
                dstContenxt = dstDevice.ImmediateContext;
                //Create sharedResource
                SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription sharedTextureDesc = dstTextureX.Description;
                sharedTextureDesc.OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.Shared;
                m_DstTexture = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(dstDevice, sharedTextureDesc);

                SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceViewDescription rvdesc = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceViewDescription
                {
                    Format = sharedTextureDesc.Format,
                    Dimension = SharpDX.Direct3D.ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture2D
                };
                rvdesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0; rvdesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
                SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceView rvptr = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceView(
                       dstDevice,
                       m_DstTexture, rvdesc);

                targetTexture = UnityEngine.Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(sharedTextureDesc.Width, sharedTextureDesc.Height, UnityEngine.TextureFormat.BGRA32, false, false, rvptr.NativePointer);
                MainCamera = UnityEngine.GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
                Display.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.RawImage>().texture = targetTexture;
                InitializeMediaPlayer();
            }, false);
```

```
   private void MediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer sender, object args)
        {
                canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(canvasDevice, frameServerDist);
                sender.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(canvasBitmap);
                var sharedResourceDst = m_DstTexture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Resource>();
                var sharedTexDst = srcDevice.OpenSharedResource<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>(sharedResourceDst.SharedHandle);
                using (var _stream = DataStream.Create(canvasBitmap.GetPixelBytes(), true, false))
                {
                    _rect.DataPointer = _stream.DataPointer;
                    _rect.Pitch = Texture2DDescription.Width * 4;
                    var srcTexture = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(srcDevice, Texture2DDescription, _rect);
                    srcContext.CopyResource(srcTexture, sharedTexDst);
                    srcContext.Flush();
                    sharedResourceDst.Dispose();
                    sharedTexDst.Dispose();
                    srcTexture.Dispose();
                }
        }
```

Comment: I think one of your issues might be UDP package size and I'ld claim the bottle neck being on the network. Up to 1500 bytes (more or less what you get for 720 * 720 * 3) is quite "guaranteed" that they all land in one UDP package (actually a bit less due to the header etc) .. if you have to much bytes to send via UDP they get split up into multiple UDP packages .. each of these individual packages might get lost -> the whole frame is lost. In addition to that unfortunately the entire Texture2D API always runs synchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was copying from CPU to GPU, the SharpDX library allowed copying frames directly to Idirect3dsurface. I'm attaching the code, maybe it will be useful.
Direct3D11 helpers is available in the microsoft documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video#helper-wrapper-classes

```
        private UnityEngine.GameObject MainCamera;
        private UnityEngine.Texture2D targetTexture;

        private IDirect3DSurface surface;
        private SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device dstDevice;
```

```
private void AppCallbacks_Initialized()
      {
          SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device srcDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware);

          UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
          {
              Display = UnityEngine.GameObject.Find("Display");
              targetTexture = null;
              //Create texture for get Device and Device context from Unity
              UnityEngine.Texture2D deviceTexture = new UnityEngine.Texture2D(2048, 2048, UnityEngine.TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
              IntPtr txPtr = deviceTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr();
              SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D dstTexture = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(txPtr);
              dstDevice = dstTexture.Device;
              //Create sharedResource

              SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription sharedTextureDesc = dstTexture.Description;
              sharedTextureDesc.OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.Shared;
              SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D m_DstTexture = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(dstDevice, sharedTextureDesc);

              SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceViewDescription rvdesc = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceViewDescription
              {
                  Format = sharedTextureDesc.Format,
                  Dimension = SharpDX.Direct3D.ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture2D
              };
              rvdesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
              rvdesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
              SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceView rvptr = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceView(
                     dstDevice,
                     m_DstTexture, rvdesc);
              targetTexture = UnityEngine.Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(sharedTextureDesc.Width, sharedTextureDesc.Height, UnityEngine.TextureFormat.BGRA32, false, false, rvptr.NativePointer);
              MainCamera = UnityEngine.GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
              Display.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.RawImage>().texture = targetTexture;
              var sharedResourceDst = m_DstTexture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Resource>();
              var sharedTexDst = srcDevice.OpenSharedResource<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>(sharedResourceDst.SharedHandle);
              surface = Direct3D11Helper.CreateDirect3DSurfaceFromSharpDXTexture(sharedTexDst);
              sharedResourceDst.Dispose();
              sharedTexDst.Dispose();
              dstTexture.Dispose();
              m_DstTexture.Dispose();
          }, false);
          InitializeMediaPlayer();
      }
```

```
private void MediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer sender, object args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("frameAvail");
            sender.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(surface);
        }
```