# How to reference FfmpegInteropX library in a Unity App zu build UWP HoloLens2 App

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, uwp, cross-platform, hololens

I tried to recreate your Mediaplayer class on hololens2 to use it to rende frames on an mrtk2 display.
Like done here:
[Livestream playback on Hololens2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71154248/livestream-playback-on-hololens2/76065254)

I could successfully reference SharpDX Lib and use Windows.X classes with `#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT` .. `#endif`. But im still struggling to reference any FfmpeggInteropX classes in my Unity Scripts.

I imported the library with NuGetForUnity Library and expected to use its referenced classes needed by the "livestream playback on hololens script"

But i was getting an error with mismatching target version (only uap10) for the library. I build my uwp app for WindowsTargetPlatform 10.0.19041, unity 2021.10.3f and .net5.0..

Can you please provide more information about a working targetVersion, unity version and buildchain version in this lib?